# How to change permanently the PATH with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: 12.04, environment-variables

To add `:/usr/local/go/bin` to the PATH with Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (Lucid) and permanently change the PATH, I just edited the files `/etc/environment` and `/etc/login.defs`.

And these modifications were OK both for my current user account and my root account.

i.e. `echo $PATH` returned the modified `PATH` for my user account as well as for the root account when using `sudo -i` or `su`.

However, this doesn't work anymore with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS when doing the same modifications if using `sudo -i`!

Meanwhile, this works when using `su`!

What should I explicitly modify to get permanently that same behavior with Precise Pangolin when using `sudo -i`?

Answer (score 1):

`sudo -i` is supposed to be a "safe" `sudo`. That means that it ignores any changes to path such that it is restricted to managed programs.

Use `sudo -s` instead if you want to load `/etc/environment` instead of using `sudo -i`.

See also:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16084/what-environment-do-i-get-with-sudo
- https://serverfault.com/questions/11899/how-to-override-a-path-environment-variable-in-sudo

Comment: Thank you so much for all the information and links. However, goodeling a pair of hours, I also found that if I modify the line secure_path of the /etc/sudoers file (using visudo) I will get the requested modified PATH when using both sudo, sudo -i and su. BTW, thank you again for your advice. Cheers. Fnux.